# How I can use pow with negative number

Tags: ios, swift

How could I use `pow` with negative number.

I use this code and it is working fine with positive.

```
let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(5))
```

How could I change this line of code to use negative numbers.

Because this part returns:

```
let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(-8)) // 1e-08
```

I need to convert one value to another and there is special formula for that.

This formula is :

```
(Mathematical formula: Value * 10 ^ -8)
```

Comment: How do you plan on rounding to a negative number of decimal places? That makes no sense. The power function is working just fine, that's how negative powers work, so your question title is really misleading.

Comment: I need to pow 10 to -8. To be able to do operations.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I update my question.

Comment: Do you know the definition of power in mathematics? It clearly seems like you don't. That is the correct result. Please include your expected result for several inputs then we might be able to figure out what mathematical function you are looking for, but it's definitely not power.

Comment: @DávidPásztor I add formula that is required to use.

Comment: `1e-08` is scientific notation that literally means `1 x 10^-8` which is exactly what you'd expect `10^(-8)` to return.

Comment: @vacawama so the pow operations is right? So how can I do this 5000 * 10 ^ 8 = 0.00005

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk as I've already stated before, that is the correct result. What you need is `5000*pow(10.0, Double(-8))`...

Comment: @OlegGordiichuk, I assume you meant `5000 * 10 ^ -8` which is just `5000 * pow(10.0, -8)` which is the same as `5000 / pow(10.0, 8)`.

Comment: It was connected with formatting issue also  I use String(format:"%f", divisor) and receive expected result. @DávidPásztor thx for help.

Comment: @vacawama yes is is right thx for help.

Comment: `0.00005` is the same as `5e-05`.

Comment: @vacawama could you pls post this like answer so I could reward you for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`1e-08` is scientific notation that literally means `1 x 10^-8` which is exactly what you'd expect `10^(-8)` to return.

> So how can I do this `5000 * 10 ^ -8 = 0.00005`?

```
5000 * pow(10.0, -8)
```

which is the same as:

```
5000 / pow(10.0, 8)
```

Note that:

`0.00005` is the same as `5e-05`